# Why Bitdefender prevent flush data (PHP)?

Tags: php, flush

This code print result after each loop to browser.Works on my host and localhost.
 but after install `bitdefender total security 2015` on my pc not works(print all text after 10 seconds at once)
i disable antivirus and firewall in bitdefender but not solved.
How to solve this?
Demo: http://s2.uploadcloud.net/2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />

            <script>
     var es;

    function startTask() {
        es = new EventSource('progress.php');

        //a message is received
        es.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
            var result = JSON.parse( e.data );

            addLog(result.message);       

            if(e.lastEventId == 'CLOSE') {
                addLog('Received CLOSE closing');
                es.close();
                var pBar = document.getElementById('progressor');
                pBar.value = pBar.max; //max out the progress bar
            }
            else {
                var pBar = document.getElementById('progressor');
                pBar.value = result.progress;
                var perc = document.getElementById('percentage');
                perc.innerHTML   = result.progress  + "%";
                perc.style.width = (Math.floor(pBar.clientWidth * (result.progress/100)) + 15) + 'px';
            }
        });

        es.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
            addLog('Error occurred');
            es.close();
        });
    }

    function stopTask() {
        es.close();
        addLog('Interrupted');
    }

    function addLog(message) {
        var r = document.getElementById('results');
        r.innerHTML += message + '<br>';
        r.scrollTop = r.scrollHeight;
    }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
              <br />
            <input type="button" onclick="startTask();"  value="Start Long Task" />
            <input type="button" onclick="stopTask();"  value="Stop Task" />
            <br />
            <br />

            <p>Results</p>
            <br />
            <div id="results" style="border:1px solid #000; padding:10px; width:300px; height:250px; overflow:auto; background:#eee;"></div>
            <br />

            <progress id='progressor' value="0" max='100' style=""></progress>  
            <span id="percentage" style="text-align:right; display:block; margin-top:5px;">0</span>
        </body>
    </html>
```

progress.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache'); 

function send_message($id, $message, $progress) {
    $d = array('message' => $message , 'progress' => $progress);
    echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "data: " . json_encode($d) . PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}

//LONG RUNNING TASK
for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    send_message($i, 'on iteration ' . $i . ' of 10' , $i*10); 
    sleep(1);
}

send_message('CLOSE', 'Process complete');
```

Comment: Are you sure it's BitDefender? What happens if you deinstall it? I know `flush` doesn't work most of the time. The fact that it's flushed (sent to the client) doesn't mean it is displayed immediately. As a matter of fact, your url gives the same issue for me, and I don't have BitDefender (anymore).

Comment: I'm sure BitDefender prevent real time print to browser. after unistall it code works fine.(after each second result print in browser)

Comment: The updated demo url does work. What did you change?

Comment: Yes i update it.(my mistake) i also instal AVG,kaspersky and eset antivirus for  test. code works fine with these antivirus.

Comment: And after fixing the mistake, BitDefender still doesn't work? Do you maybe have some InternetScanning feature enabled in BitDefender? In that case, maybe BitDefender buffers the page until it is fully loaded, so it can scan it.

Comment: Yes doesn't work. i disabled all feature like antivirus,firewall,web protection,antispam,... but not works.

Comment: You might try to contact BitDefender and report this behavior.

Comment: Thanks @GolezTrol for reply. i contact them but not answer me yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in BitDefender. they solved it now.